# Delaying jtextfield document listener for validation

Tags: java, textfield, documentlistener

I'm trying to check a JFormattedTextField after a value has been entered to make sure it does not match any other values entered in the other similar fields. It becomes a real pain if this check happens repeatedly while the user is typing because I want to provide an error message and I need to implement a number of changes if the value changes. But inputs like 123 will match 12 before the 3 is typed even though no error has really been made yet. Thus the need for a delay. So I'm trying to use a document listener but delay it until the user has validated (as accepted by the text field, by action or shifting focus) the entry.

I thought I had a good method, and it nearly works. My plan was to use a document listener to set up focus and action listeners. Unfortunately, I seem to end up with tons of focus and action listeners since the document listener keeps adding them. That means the error message and subsequent processing happen a ridiculous number of times instead of once. I've tried two work-arounds: 1) remove focus and action listeners before adding new ones, and 2) use a boolean to mark the existence of the focus and action listeners to avoid creating them again.

sscce (I'm new here, should I leave out all the includes?):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Tester {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Tester window = new Tester();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Tester() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 50);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField = new JTextField("Change this.");
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                trigger();
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                trigger();
            }
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                trigger();
            }
            public void trigger() {
                textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    }
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You changed the text to: " + textField.getText());
                    }
                });
                textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You changed the text to: " + textField.getText());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        frame.add(textField);
    }
}
```

So attempted fix 1 was to place textField.removeFocusListener(null) and textField.removeActionListener(null) just before the two textField.add... lines. Nothing changed from attempted fix 1. Attempted fix 2 was to create a boolean triggeringEvent outside of trigger() and then start trigger() with if(triggeringEvent == false) { triggeringEvent = true; ... all the focus and action listener lines. Attempted fix 2 just left me with nothing triggering at all.

Thank you for any insight anyone can provide!!!

Edit: I had tried Boann's addChangeListener, but that triggers incessantly, too, and it even triggers when the value hasn't been changed.

Edit: I thought I found a solution by adjusting attempted fix 2, but it fails with more than one JTextField:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Tester {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private boolean eventTrigger = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Tester window = new Tester();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Tester() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 50);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField = new JTextField("Change this.");
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(eventTrigger == false) {
                    trigger();
                }
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(eventTrigger == false) {
                    trigger();
                }
            }
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            public void trigger() {
                eventTrigger = true;
                textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    }
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You changed the text to: " + textField.getText());
                        eventTrigger = false;
                    }
                });
                textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You changed the text to: " + textField.getText());
                        eventTrigger = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        frame.add(textField);
    }
}
```

You can see in this. If you start hopping between fields there are a whole bunch of extra times it triggers. It works fine for the first one you try adjusting, but then it fails.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Tester {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private boolean eventTrigger = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Tester window = new Tester();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Tester() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,0,0));

        textField1 = new JTextField("Change the first.");
        textField2 = new JTextField("Change the second.");
        textField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(eventTrigger == false) {
                    trigger();
                }
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(eventTrigger == false) {
                    trigger();
                }
            }
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            public void trigger() {
                eventTrigger = true;
                textField1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    }
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You changed the text to: " + textField1.getText());
                        eventTrigger = false;
                    }
                });
                textField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You changed the text to: " + textField1.getText());
                        eventTrigger = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        textField2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(eventTrigger == false) {
                    trigger();
                }
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(eventTrigger == false) {
                    trigger();
                }
            }
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            public void trigger() {
                eventTrigger = true;
                textField2.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    }
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You changed the text to: " + textField2.getText());
                        eventTrigger = false;
                    }
                });
                textField2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You changed the text to: " + textField2.getText());
                        eventTrigger = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        panel.add(textField1);
        panel.add(textField2);
        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see any JFormattedTextFields in your code, but if `textField` is in fact a JFormattedTextField, I would avoid DocumentListeners and FocusListeners, and just use `textField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", e -> trigger());`.  If it is not a JFormattedTextField, I would consider using an InputVerifier.

Comment: I had tried to simplify the code as much as possible while illustrating the behavior, plus I'm planning to do the same soon with regular JTextFields. But, yes, sorry, I probably should have used JFormattedTextFields. addPropertyChangeListener has similar problems, firing off sometimes even when the value hasn't changed. I think it may be easier to fix, though, because I think I see the pattern to its false positives. Then I just need to change all the JTextFields to JFormattedTextFields.

Comment: Thanks, VGR. Going back to addPropertyChangeListener and dealing with its false positives is working much better. Since the prior value is also held elsewhere in an integer, the conditional statement to see if I'm getting a true positive or a false positive isn't so hard to implement, and the issues that arise in the process are easily enough handled by try-catch. It still bugs be that if I weren't recording the value elsewhere, addPropertyChangeListener's false positives would be really hard to catch. But things are working now. Thanks for the help.